# Qual o tamanho máximo de um objeto em 32 e 64 bits?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, objetos

Especificamente o *array* pode ter até 4 bilhões de elementos, eu acho, e os tamanhos mais comuns de tamanho dos elementos deve ser 4, 8 ou 16 bytes.

Pergunto, qual o tamanho máximo que o objeto pode ocupar na memória? Seria 4 GB em 32 bits? É ilimitado em 64 bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se por objeto você quer dizer um *array*, `System.Array` utiliza um `Int32` como índice - então seu limite é definido por `System.Int32.MaxValue` ( 2.147.483.647, ou `0x7FFFFFFF` em hexadecimal.)

O limite pré-.Net 4.5 [era de 1.2GiB](http://www.centerspace.net/large-matrices-and-vectors). Era possível forçar o limite para 2.4GiB. Hoje em dia o tamanho máximo de endereçamento é [24TiB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2016), porém apenas em ambientes 64-bit, com a seguinte definição no arquivo `.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Fontes: [1](http://www.centerspace.net/large-matrices-and-vectors), [2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/).

Comment: Se for apenas o tamanho do array tem essa "limitação" de itens que ele possui, bem observado.

Comment: @HarlanGomesNascimento Exato, e tem ainda o fato de que, mesmo o construtor permitindo a inicialização de um `array` com um `long`, o objeto final ainda não suporta um index do tipo `long`.

Comment: Com a opção `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects ` o índice pode usar `System.UInt32.MaxValue`, portanto pode ir além dos 2 bilhões de elementos.

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia. Obrigado pela dica @bigown!

Answer (score 3):

Depende muito da versão do .NET Framework que você for usar, versões anterior a 4.5 tinha um limite de 2 GB que poderia ser um problema para a cache em sistemas "grandes";

Com o a versão 4.5 foi introduzido a funcionalidade "gcAllowVeryLargeObjects" que permite em sistemas 64 bits usar maiores quantidades de RAM;

Acredito que o programa vai ficar limitado a quantidade de RAM que a versão do Windows consegue usar:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx